How to run AWS SAM Build - Binary validation failed for go?
I'm trying to build aws sam in my local. I'm running into the following issue even though the go is in the PATH. How can I fix it? Thanks in advance!
$ sam build
Building codeuri: path/to/path runtime: provided.al2 metadata: {'BuildMethod': 'go1.x'} architecture:
x86_64 functions: x/y
Workflow GoModulesBuilder does not support value "False" for building in source. Using default value "True".

Build Failed
Error: GoModulesBuilder:Validation - Binary validation failed for go, searched for go in following locations  : ['/usr/local/bin/go'] which did not satisfy constraints for runtime: provided. Do you have go for runtime: provided on your PATH?

Versions
➜  ~ ls /usr/local/bin/go
/usr/local/bin/go
➜  ~ go version
go version go1.21.5 darwin/amd64
➜  ~ sam --version
SAM CLI, version 1.118.0


What does /usr/local/bin/go version print?
